# How to convert the below JS code to ES6 class code

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I am trying to do something with my UI. for that I am trying to convert the below code to ES6 code. Can anyone please help me? I tried from my side. but don't know where I am getting the error.

```
const progress = document.getElementById('progress')
const prev = document.getElementById('prev')
const next = document.getElementById('next')
const circles = document.querySelectorAll('.circle')

let currentActive = 1

next.addEventListener('click', () => {
    currentActive++;

    if(currentActive > circles.length) {
        currentActive = circles.length
    }

    update()
})

prev.addEventListener('click', () => {
    currentActive--

    if(currentActive < 1) {
        currentActive = 1
    }

    update()
})

function update() {
    circles.forEach((circle, idx) => {
        if(idx < currentActive) {
            circle.classList.add('active')
        } else {
            circle.classList.remove('active')
        }
    })

    const actives = document.querySelectorAll('.active')

    progress.style.width = (actives.length - 1) / (circles.length - 1) * 100 + '%'

    if(currentActive === 1) {
        prev.disabled = true
    } else if(currentActive === circles.length) {
        next.disabled = true
    } else {
        prev.disabled = false
        next.disabled = false
    }
}
```

please let me know.

```
class abcd{
}
```

Comment: What you have is valid ES6 code already. Why would you change that into a `class`?

Comment: @Bergi, thanks for the reply, just curious to know how to write in Class format.

Comment: @Sanju Well, you don't, that's the point. There is no "class format" that any code can be written "in", classes are a specific structure that fits well only in specific cases. Start by learning OOP, and figure out whether (and if: how) it can be applied to your case. Will you have multiple objects with similar behaviour?

Comment: Can you please post the error?

Comment: @GandalfTheGrey i am not getting any error also. but not getting the output also.